# Closing a program running under another users profile using C#

Tags: c#

I made a program that opens COM6. The program starts when the user logs on.
If another user logs on, while the first user is still logged in, the program crazes because the COM is already open.
I found this code, which I thought could solve the problem. The code was meant to close all other application with the same name, but apparently, it does not work, when the other app is running under another user. Have anybody got any solution for this ?

```
void CloseAllButMe()
    {
        Process[] processes;
        Process self = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(self.ProcessName);
        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            if (self.Id != p.Id) p.CloseMainWindow();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Are you logged in as an administrator?

Comment: Sounds like the actual solution would be to convert the application to a service, not crash one user's application so another can run it

Comment: There are a lot of cons too so read up on this first, but you could make a singleton class that handles COM6 communication so it can be used from both program instances. A possible better solution might be to check if the port is already open before opening. If it already is open use the open port.

Comment: If another user session has the port open, it's rude just to pull the plug on it (as if by magic, from the other user's perspective). Correct error reporting to allow the user to address this problem is all that is needed.

Comment: I am logged on as administrator.
It’s not really a crash only a message about that the COM is not avaliubel
Singleton– hmm. But I think, if I do not close apps under other users, I will not be able to access the comport. I can’t use the comport when another user have opened it.
It’s not rude to close the other users program. The programs starts up as soon as the user log on again. No problem :)
I will try to user the code below :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the methods `Process.Kill`  to stop a process. Calling Kill will immediately stop the process and could cause a loss of work.

Here is a code sample for killing Calculator:

```
public static void KillPaint()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process[] procs = null;

    try
    {
        procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("calc");

        Process mspaintProc = procs[0];

        if (!mspaintProc.HasExited)
        {
            mspaintProc.Kill();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (procs != null)
        {
            foreach (Process p in procs)
            {
                p.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```